# Create Folders and Log Details to Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to write a script that creates a child folder inside of every folder within a designated parent folder. This part works fine. However the script also needs to log the folder name and URL to a separate spreadsheet in columns A & B. This is what I can't seem to get working. I'm still a little green with JS so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var folders = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxx').getFolders();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('xxxxx').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var counter = 0;  

while (folders.hasNext()){
  var folder = folders.next();
  var folderName = folder.getName();
  var folderUrl = folder.createFolder("Child Folder - " + folderName);
  counter++
    for (i = 0; i < counter.length; i++){
      var valueRange = ss.getRange(i,1,1,2);
      var values = [[folderName, folderUrl]];
      range.setValues(valueRange);
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested but chnaging `range.setValues(valueRange);` to `valueRange.setValues(values);` may work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part is incorrect:

```
var valueRange = ss.getRange(i,1,1,2);
var values = [[folderName, folderUrl]];
range.setValues(valueRange);
```

If this is your full code you have not listed a variable called `range`. Second, you have used `valueRange` instead of `values`. So third line should be

```
valueRange.setValues(values)
```

Also, be careful when using a strictly set range and custom made array. The number rows **must exactly** match the number of the array top level length and the columns **must exactly** match the number of second level length.

In other words:

```
array.length = total rows of range
array[i].length = highest number of columns of the range
```

so instead create your `values` array first and then you can do `ss.getRange(i, 1, values.length, values[0].length)` which will always allow you to do `valueRange.setValues(values)`

**EDIT:** additional problems

```
for (i = 0; i < counter.length; i++){
  var valueRange = ss.getRange(i,1,1,2);
  var values = [[folderName, folderUrl]];
  range.setValues(valueRange);
}
```

1. This loop will always overwrite the first row
2. `getRange(firstRow, firstColumn , numRows, numCols)` the lowest possible number for each one is `1` however you have `i = 0`

You do not need the `for` loop here. You can either output to spreadsheet directly (not efficient and against Google recommendations) or output to a new 2D array (read about the `push` method in Javascript for arrays). Without changing too much you can do:

```
counter = 1 // if you want to always overwrite row 1 in the spreadsheet
//OR (use only 1 of these 2 lines)
counter = ss.getLastRow() //if you always want to append after last row in spreadsheet

while (folders.hasNext()){
  var folder = folders.next();
  var folderName = folder.getName();
  var folderUrl = folder.createFolder("Child Folder - " + folderName);
  counter++
  var values = [[folderName, folderUrl]]
  ss.getRange(counter, 1, 1, 2).setValues(values)
}
```

Comment: I corrected the error you pointed out and changed the for loop to reference the length of the counter so the array would no longer be fixed. Its still not working however.

Comment: @rylaughlin I missed another problem `for (i = 0; i < counter.length; i++)` should be `for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)`. Although I have to say the purpose of the loop escapes me. You do not perform any actions that warrant using a for loop inside of the while loop.

Comment: I thought a for loop would be required to print each folder to a new line on a spreadsheet. I'd love to know if there is a better way. At least this is beginning to work, however after making this change i is no longer accepted in the for loop's range, so only one line is being printed.

Comment: @rylaughlin you are already using a `while` loop to create folders. As you create a new folder all you need to do is output the name of the folder. While this is the least optimal way of doing it this would work. In addition your for loop makes it so **only the last created folder** gets output to the spreadsheet. Think of it this way, you created your 5th folder. The `for` loo will write the name into rows 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 because you always star from the beginning (`getRange(i,1,1,2)`. Speaking of which, your for loop starts from 0, but in this case the lowest possible number for `i` is 1

Comment: @rylaughlin see my edited answer for how the loop would look like using your method

Comment: That's great, it works perfectly now. I see what you mean now that a for loop wasn't needed. Thanks so much for your help!